# Angular/NgRx - Conditional select and dispatch

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a relatively simple case where i want select and dispatch only one of 2 select/dispatch according to a condition.

not conditioned code:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select(fromChallengesSelectors.getSelectedMyChallenge),
      tap((challenge: Challenge) => {
        if (!challenge) {
          this.store.dispatch(new fromChallengesActions.SelectMyChallengeAction(this.challengeId));
        }
      }),
      filter((challenge: Challenge) => !!challenge),
// .....
);
```

now i want to do either
`select(fromChallengesSelectors.getSelectedMyChallenge)` + `this.store.dispatch(new fromChallengesActions.SelectMyChallengeAction (this.challengeId))`

or

`select(fromChallengesSelectors.getSelectedNetworkChallenge)` + `this.store.dispatch(new fromChallengesActions .SelectNetworkChallengeAction (this.challengeId))`

according to the value of `this.route.data.profil`, the rest of the code will remain the same

there is way to do it with the `iff` operator for example?